# Opencart Error needed a fix

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I cannot understand this error. Can anyone help me.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: E-Mail to required!' in /home/projects/public_html/system/storage/modification/system/library/mail.php:94
Stack trace:
#0 /home/projects/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_catalog_model_checkout_order.php(1619): Mail->send()
#1 [internal function]: ModelCheckoutOrder->addOrderHistory(145031, 2440, '<p>Hi ,</p>\r\n\r\n...', true, true)
#2 /home/projects/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_system_engine_loader.php(150): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Loader->{closure}(Array)
#4 /home/projects/public_html/system/engine/proxy.php(13): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Array)
#5 /home/projects/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_api_order.php(841): Proxy->__call('addOrderHistory', Array)
#6 /home/projects/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_api_order.php(841): Proxy->addOrderHistory(145031, 2440, '<p>Hi ,</p>\r\n\r\n...', true, true)
#7 [internal function]: Controller in /home/projects/public_html/system/storage/modification/system/library/mail.php on line 94
```

Comment: What happens in the given line of your code?

Comment: you can check this link, it seems the same problem
https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=142719

Comment: I think if you  googled, you would find it easily

Comment: What is your OpenCart version?

Comment: a mail is sent to the customer @NicoHaase

Comment: can't find the answer @mfadel can you help me with the link if you got any

Comment: Opencart Version 2.2.0.0 @DigitCart

Answer (score 0):

Seems like in the new OC release somebody have forgotten to change mail_smtp_host to mail_smtp_hostname in ALL files! 
But Im not surprised, SMTP mail transport in OC have never worked good from the beginning :P

You have two options look for config_mail_smtp_host and change it to config_mail_smtp_hostname in all files (about 30 of them) or wait till 2.0.2.1 release because it seems that it is fixed there.
There is also a third way, temporary revert back config_mail_smtp_hostname in admin settings files to config_mail_smtp_host (JUST 2 files to edit).

Im posting the last solution here because it is the easiest one.

Edit this file admin/controller/setting/setting.php and find the following code:

```
`if (isset($this->request->post['config_mail_smtp_hostname'])) {                                                                                                                                                              
$data['config_mail_smtp_hostname'] = $this->request->post['config_mail_smtp_hostname'];                                                                                                                              
else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
$data['config_mail_smtp_hostname'] = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');                                                                                                                                
} `if (isset($this->request->post['config_mail_smtp_host'])) {                                                                                                                                                              
$data['config_mail_smtp_host'] = $this->request->post['config_mail_smtp_host'];                                                                                                                              
else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
$data['config_mail_smtp_host'] = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_host');                                                                                                                                
}
```

now change all config_mail_smtp_hostname occureces to config_mail_smtp_host so the code will look like:
Code:

```
    if (isset($this->request->post['config_mail_smtp_host'])) {                                                                                                                                                              
$data['config_mail_smtp_host'] = $this->request->post['config_mail_smtp_host'];                                                                                                                              
else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
$data['config_mail_smtp_host'] = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_host');                                                                                                                                
}
```

Now edit this file:
admin/view/template/setting/setting.tpl
find this code:

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-mail-smtp-hostname"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $help_mail_smtp_hostname; ?>"><?php echo $entry_mail_smtp_hostname; ?></span></label>                     
            <div class="col-sm-10">                                                                                                                                                                                                      
              <input type="text" name="config_mail_smtp_hostname" value="<?php echo $config_mail_smtp_hostname; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_mail_smtp_hostname; ?>" id="input-mail-smtp-hostname" class="form-control" />
```

and change it to :

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-mail-smtp-host"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $help_mail_smtp_hostname; ?>"><?php echo $entry_mail_smtp_hostname; ?></span></label>                         
            <div class="col-sm-10">                                                                                                                                                                                                      
              <input type="text" name="config_mail_smtp_host" value="<?php echo $config_mail_smtp_host; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_mail_smtp_hostname; ?>" id="input-mail-smtp-host" class="form-control" />
```

That should do the trick.
Ah, and you need to set SMTP Hostname in the admin again!

[OC 1.5.x and 2.x SMTP email from field error fix](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=20380)

Comment: its version 2.2 @kareem

Answer (score 0):

One or more modifications are affecting this file:

```
catalog_model_checkout_order.php
```

You have:

```
Mail->send()
```

But seems that something like this is missed on that file:

```
$mail->setTo($order_info['email']);
```

You can edit the following file:

```
vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_catalog_model_checkout_order.php
```

Search for all occurrence of `Mail->send()` specially the one that is around line 1619.

There must be `$mail->setTo` near that, if it doesn't exists, add it your self: `$mail->setTo('your-email@example.com');`

If this fixed your issue, you must check your modifications to find which one is causing this issue.

Note that above file is a temporary file and will be lost when you clear caches.

Comment: it is already there @DigitCart can you let me know how can i check this error in view

Comment: Try to disabling your modifications one by one.